# Correct tag-markdown display in sub/sup HTML

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, markdown

Tag-markdown is not fully-supported in `<sub>` and/or `<sup>` specifications as it retains its default font size:

```
This is a [meta-tag:feature-request].

<sub><sup>
This is a [meta-tag:feature-request].
</sup></sub>
```

renders as

> This is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).
>
> <sub><sup>This is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).</sup></sub>

Is it possible adjust the font size to suit `<sub>`/`<sup>` HTML tags?

Comment: a<sub>b</sub> in comments?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that makes any sense. A post tag has a defined font size for that class, and it should not be altered by its placement within other elements. Would you also expect a header element to shrink down to the same size as its parent subscript element too?

```
<sub><h1>Should this shrink?</h1></sub>
```

## Should this shrink?

I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, I would. I'm sure others would agree.

Comment: @Werner But CSS is explicitly designed to achieve exactly the *opposite* effect that you're desiring. You set an explicit font-size to *prevent* other elements from altering the appearance of that element. If you want something to expand or shrink with the text around it, you don't set a font-size. Changing this to the effect you desire would require an additional selector for *every single* element you could expect inside a subscript element, to change the size to be smaller. That's simply unrealistic and unexpected.

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with CSS (sigh...). Your example related to `<h1>` specifically sets the font/is a font-related HTML tag, while I don't think `[tagging]` is/should be.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the font size of `[tag:<tag>]` markdown is *similar* to the first-level `<sub>`/`<sup>`-style, therefore no shrinkage is really necessary. For example,

```
feature-request feature-request

feature-request feature-request

feature-request feature-request
```

Deeper-level tag markdown formatting still seem out-of-place.

However, it is implemented to some extent. The iOS app shows the following output:

> [image]

There is a clear difference in the font size of the `[tag:<tag>]` formatting.